# Probability Independent Events when dealing with the Null Set

Tags: probability

I have been reading this section on [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)). It states that for two independent events $A$ and $B$ that $Pr(A)=\frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}=Pr(A|B)$ if and only if $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)Pr(B)$. Shouldn't it say $Pr(B)\neq 0$ for this to occur? You assume $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\underbrace{Pr(B)}_{=0}=0$ and then you get $Pr(A)=\frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}=Pr(A|B)$ and divide by zero which would be a counterexample right? I could be misinterpreting the wording but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The wiki actually has the following paragraph below that bit which acknowledges the issue you raise: "Thus, the occurrence of B does not affect the probability of A, and vice versa. Although the derived expressions may seem more intuitive, they are not the preferred definition, as the conditional probabilities may be undefined if P(A) or P(B) are 0. Furthermore, the preferred definition makes clear by symmetry that when A is independent of B, B is also independent of A."

Comment: So do you say that two events A and B are independent if and only if $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)Pr(B)$? Or, do you say that two events A and B are independent if and only if $Pr(A)=Pr(A|B)$?

Comment: @Srikant I get what you are saying, never mind about the question, I get it. I think it's kinda lame to mention right after the definition to say that it may be undefined in some cases. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: The first is the preferred definition but we can use the second one as well as long as we remember that the definition only applies if $P(B)>0$. After all, the second one does convey some inutition about what independence means:  if two events $A$ and $B$ are independent then our assessment of the chances of $A$ happening do not change if we knew $B$ happened

Comment: I did not know that the first was the preferred definition. Thank you, again. I'll just be cognizant when using it.

Comment: An escape route that makes it possible to still use the second as definition might be a convention: let's define $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ if $P(B)>0$ and $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$ otherwise. In the special case $P(B)=0$ independence (according to the first definition) is allready guaranteed because it implies that also $P(A\cap B)=0$.